# How to test dashboard without re-login?

Tags: testing, mocha.js, cypress

I am recently working with cypress would like to test a web dashboard. How do I make test without re-login ?
I try to make action (`it`) within one describe. However it direct me to the login page.

```
describe("Overview Page", () => {
   before("Behaviour to overview page", () => {
       cy.SignIn();
    });

 it("Overview Page Check", () => {
    cy.intercept({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://api.mapbox.com/**",
    }).as("da

taMapbox");

cy.intercept({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://api/v2/**",
}).as("dataDas");

cy.contains("Park").click();
cy.wait("@dataMapbox", { timeout: 90000 })
  .its("response.statusCode")
  .should("equal", 200);

cy.wait("@dataDas", { timeout: 90000 })
  .its("response.statusCode")
  .should("equal", 200);
// sidebar
cy.get(".toc > .attached").as("sidebar");
cy.get("@sidebar").should("be.visible");
// page loaded
cy.wait(15000);
cy.get(".twelve > .header").should("have.text", "Overview");

// current and dismiss
cy.get(
  ':nth-child(1) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > .active'
).click();
cy.get(
  ':nth-child(1) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > :nth-child(2)'
).click();
cy.get(
  ':nth-child(1) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > .active'
).click();

cy.get(
  ':nth-child(2) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > .active'
).click();
cy.get(
  ':nth-child(2) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > :nth-child(2)'
).click();
cy.get(
  ':nth-child(2) > .top > [style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: flex-end;"] > .ui > .active'
).click();

for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  cy.get('[data-tooltip="Map rotate 45 degree anticlockwise."]').click();
}

for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  cy.get('[data-tooltip="Map rotate 45 degree clockwise."]').click();
}
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Fullscreen"]').click();
cy.wait(3000);
cy.get('[data-tooltip="CloseFullscreen"]').click();
cy.wait(3000);

cy.get(".ellipsis").click();
cy.contains("Edit Project Info").click();

//header
cy.get(".basic > .grid > .column > .ui", { timeout: 500000 }).should(
  "be.visible"
);
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Add"]').should("be.visible").click();
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Extrude"]').click();
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Edit"]').click();
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Move"]').click();
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Scale"]').click();
cy.get('[data-tooltip="Rotate"]').click();

// back to overview
    cy.get("@sidebar").contains("Overview").should("be.visible").click();
    cy.get(".twelve > .header", { timeout: 15000 }).should(
      "have.text",
      "Overview"
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and could solve it by adding

```js
beforeEach(function () {
        cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()
    })
```

in the `describe` suite.